# Como e aonde aprender Sockets em C#

Tags: c#

Estou estudando C# e resolvi aprender um pouco sobre Sockets e Conexões, porém, ainda estou com dúvidas sobre como estudar Sockets e aonde achar conteúdo sobre o mesmo, vocês tem livros ou recomendações de algum local que seja bom para estudar esse conteúdo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A documentação da Microsoft melhorou bastante comparada a como era antes e dispõe de um conteúdo extenso e muito bem detalhado sobre C#, F# etc. incluindo [Sockets](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets?view=net-5.0). A documentação disponibiliza diversos artigos, exemplos de uso com uma lista de métodos, classes, propriedades e *namespaces* de várias APIs e assuntos diferentes. Digo, por experiência, que é um excelente recurso para estudar C#.

Outro local que também inclui uma excelente documentação em tudo o que envolve a Web (e portanto, conexões também incluindo o assunto Sockets) é a [documentação da Mozilla, também com Sockets utilizando C#](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_server).

A partir dos recursos "teóricos" e outros relacionados, recomendo que faça algum projeto que envolva o que aprendeu por leitura para fixar o conhecimento e descobrir novas coisas dentro do assunto e casos de uso de cada funcionalidade que foi disponibilizada por um framework, tecnologia e/ou linguagem que está aprendendo. Também recomendo que **não apenas copie e cole o código, entenda o que está sendo feito**. O conhecimento sobre a(s) ferramenta(s) virá a partir de estudo e prática consistentes.

Espero ter ajudado de alguma forma.

Answer (score 0):

Olha, eu sei que você esta buscando por C#, mas se quiser tentar aprofundar mais e ir mais na base do negócio um dos melhores materiais sobre o assunto e gratuito - para iniciar - que se tem hoje é talvez este:

Começaria com IPC (comunicação entre processos) - Se não tem nenhuma noção ainda
http://www.beej.us/guide/bgipc/

Depois iria para Socket TCP, seguido de UDP e por ultima deixaria outros tipos.
http://www.beej.us/guide/bgnet/

Também recomendo a leitura do livro do Tanenbaum e Wetherall sobre Redes de Computadores, mas camadas de transporte, que apesar de não ser uma leitura simples é o que tem mais de mais refinado em livros sobre o assunto de redes. Já que livro não é algo auditável então o povo escreve um monte de porcaria descartável por ai e com rótulo de qualidade.

Com um VM, um debian só interface texto virtualizada você faz muita coisa com isso. Entendendo o fundamento do socket, você aplica facilmente em C#.
Se for no windows, não é tão diferente já que basicamente é copia, mas tem umas diretivas que tem que iniciar antes de começar a operar o socket no Windows e estes adicionais são dispensaveis no entendimento do socket.

Aconselho também o uso de ferramentas como TCP dump e nmap - Wireshark e Zenmap e ambas as doc são muito boas. São tipo seu debugger de rede, e olha, sem eles é muito dificil achar um erro, não adianta dar print na variável ai que o negocio as vezes não é tão banal.

Outros materias muito bons para entender o conceito do socket são:

Manual excelente da GNU:
https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Sockets.html

O proprio manual de socket:
https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html

Funcao Socket:
https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html

Com isso ai vai te dar uma boa base do que como funciona, esses manuais não são só explicando como montar a função, e sim um conjunto de como ele faz para funcionar.

Tem outros materiais bons. Mas estes que eu te passei pois foram os que usei tanto na época que fiz meu tcc usando fazendo um servidor de jogos, passando por varios,  até quando escrevi um guia sobre socket, se eu pudesse enviaria junto.